# Wordpress Export Import Site Navigation Menu

Tags: menus, navigation, import, export

When I do an export and import the menus get transferred but I have to set the Site Navigation Menu manualy. Obviously it's only a small detail but can I ask is this a bug or expected behaviour and is there any way to include the site navigation menu selection in the export file.

The same thing is the case for custom menu widgets.

Comment: Have you tried [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/menu-exporter/)? I know it hasn't been updated in awhile, but it should still work with the latest version of WP, and it's by a very reputable developer

Comment: This plugin no longer works for me.

Answer (score 2):

The data for Currently Active Menus is not included in the exports (by default). This is because there is no guarantee the importing site will have the same theme (or same named menus).

If changing the menus was a big deal, you could export/import all the data straight out of the database. *(This option is strongly discouraged!)*

Comment: Thanks. No I just wanted to clarify whether there was some way to include it any why it was missing.

Comment: Not sure why this is strongly discouraged if someone is keeping the same domain, theme and plugins. There is a lot of data that isn't exported via the wordpress plugin, including images.

Automattic, if you are listening, it's 2017. Please fix your plugin!